# Update IEnumerable with new object in extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

I would like to add new iEnumerable object to original one. Can I do this updating original object in extenstion method like following?

```
public static void AddItems<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> orginalColl,    
IEnumerable<TSource> collectionToAdd)
{
foreach (var item in collectionToAdd)
{
    orginalColl.ToList<TSource>().Add(item);             
}             
}
```

I am calling  like this: OrgCollecation.AddItems(newCollection).
But this does not seems to work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IEnumerable[<T>]` ***is not intended*** for adding. You can *concatenate* (generating a new sequence), but that doesn't change the original sequence (/list/array/etc). You can do that with `Enumerable.Concat`, i.e. `return orginalColl.Concat(...)`. But emphasis: *this does not update the original collection*.

What you *could* do would be to cast to `IList[<T>]` or similar, but *that would be abusive* (and will only work for some scenarios, not all). It won't work, for example, for anything that is based on an iterator block (or any other `IEnumerable<T>` that is not also an `IList<T>`) - for example it won't work on `someSource.Where(predicte)`.

If you expect to change the source, then you should be **passing in** something like `IList[<T>]`. For example:

```
public static void AddItems<TSource>(this IList<TSource> orginalColl,
    IEnumerable<TSource> collectionToAdd)
{
    foreach (var item in collectionToAdd)
    {
        orginalColl.Add(item);             
    }             
}
```

(btw, `AddRange` would be an alternative name for the above, to match `List<T>.AddRange`)

Answer (score 2):

No you can not.
In your code you are cloning the source enumerable into list, then adding elements to it and forgetting, because you are not returning anything.

Try

```
var result = orginalColl.Concat(collectionToAdd);
```

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

In short, an `IEnumerable<T>` should be considered immutable, and you can't add to it. You don't know what kind of collection is implementing it, it may for example be a serial port input or a read only file in the file system you're enumerating from.

What you're trying to do to the collection matches the use case of `ICollection<T>` better; it's implemented by generic (mutable) collections in the framework.

```
public static void AddItems<TSource>(this ICollection<TSource> orginalColl,
        IEnumerable<TSource> collectionToAdd)
{
    foreach (var item in collectionToAdd)
    {
        orginalColl.Add(item);
    }
}
```